# How to obtain and load a good initial data set for object localization?

Tags: python, cnn, data, object-detection

I'm looking for a good data set for training a CNN based network to do object localization (i.e. a data set with class labels and bounding box data).

What is a good initial data set to use?

How can I obtain and load all the data (images, labels, bounding boxes)?

I'm using python, so a python-friendly data source is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The ones that are available out of the box -

1. [Open Images Dataset (Object Detection Track)](https://www.kaggle.com/c/google-ai-open-images-object-detection-track)
2. [MS COCO dataset](http://cocodataset.org/)
3. [Indoor Objects Detection](https://github.com/bircatmcri/MCIndoor20000)
4. [ILSVRC dataset](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/)

**Create your own**

1. Search for the object of interest on Google Images (like bikes, cars etc.)
2. Use the Fatkun Chrome browser plugin to download all images at once
3. Use [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) to annotate and generate a custom dataset
4. Use pre-trained models like SSD MobileNet to re-train your own models

Might not be an exhaustive one, but it will definitely get you started. Cheers!